# Format "visited on" date in "dd Month yyyy" format (example: "1 October 2006") in references list

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, date

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,date=year,urldate=long,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{markey}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It creates this reference list:

> Markey, Nicolas (2005). *Tame the BeaST. The B to X of BibTeX.* Version 1.3. URL: `http://mirror.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf` (visited on 1st October 2006).

The `urldate = 2006-10-01` in the bib file is displayed as `1st October 2006`. But I want it to look like `1 October 2006`.

Is there some biblatex option to change the urldate format to like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have exhausted the data options and are still not happy with the results, you have to modify the date formatting macros directly. In this case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,date=year,urldate=long,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{markey}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (visited on 1 October 2006)]

The original definition can be found in [`british.lbx`, ll. 20-31, v3.18b](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/418a71a9c6f54014016b483d63e8fc0e966edfca/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/british.lbx#L20-L31).