# Can I use "australian" option only for \mkbibdatelong but use "british" for everything else?

Tags: biblatex, languages, date

I have two code examples here.

#### Option `british` for `babel`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,date=year,urldate=long,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{markey}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

> Markey, Nicolas (2005). *Tame the BeaST. The B to X of BibTeX.* Version 1.3. URL: `http://mirror.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf` (visited on 1st October 2006).

#### Option `australian` for `babel`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[australian]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,date=year,urldate=long,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{markey}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

> Markey, Nicolas (2005). *Tame the BeaST.* The B to X of BibTeX. Version 1.3. url: `http://mirror.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf` (visited on 1 October 2006).

I want this output. This output has "1 October 2006" and I want this. The previous output had "1st October 2006" which I do not want.

#### My question

Now apparently the file `texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/australian.lbx` has only this:

```
\ProvidesFile{australian.lbx}
[\abx@lbxid]

\InheritBibliographyExtras{british}
\DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibyeardivisiondateshort#1#2{%
    \mkbibyeardivision{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
    \mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibyeardivisiondatelong#1#2{%
    \mkbibyeardivision{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
    \mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
}

\InheritBibliographyStrings{english}

\endinput
```

It looks like `australian.lbx` redefines only a few date formats but it is otherwise same as `british.lbx` (because it inherits british). Is it possible to tell biblatex to use `australian` only for `\mkbibdatelong` but `british` for everything else?

If not for this preferred date format (per our university style guide), I am supposed to be using `british` for everything else. But since `australian` inherits `british` and gives this preferred date format, I am considering using `australian`. So my question is can I just use `australian.lbx` to produce the output I want? Or would doing so lead to problems later?

I know I can always explicitly redefine `\mkbibdatelong` myself (like shown in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672612/18587) but I was thinking why duplicate code that is already present in `australian.lbx`? So I still want to know if simply using `\usepackage[australian]{babel}` is going to lead me to problems later?

To summarize my questions:

1. Can using `\usepackage[australian]{babel}` cause problems when I want british style for the rest of the document?
2. Is there a way to tell biblatex to use `australian` only for `\mkbibdatelong` and use `british` for everything else?

Comment: Isn't `australian.lbx` doing exactly what you want?

Comment: @Cicada Yes, and that is why I ask this question. To understand if using `australian` (when I would otherwise normally use `british`) could lead to any problems that I cannot foresee right now. More experienced LaTeX users and developers might be able to tell me whether it is a bad idea to use `australian` when my original intention was to use `british`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Q1: What if I use `\usepackage[australian]{babel}` instead of `\usepackage[british]{babel}`?

Since `australian.lbx` inherits its strings from `english.lbx` and not `british.lbx`, you'll see a difference for the strings that differ between `english` and `british`. At the moment strings that differ are is `organizer`, `organizers`  and `byorganizer` (British has "organiser" etc., while English and thus also Australian has "organizer").

Furthermore, if you load `babel` with the `australian` option instead of `british`, your entire document will use `babel`'s Australian localisation. For `babel` the Australian localisation differs from the British localisation only in the date format (analogous to the difference in `biblatex`'s date format for those languages). In particular the hyphenation patterns are the same.

Other packages that react to the global language settings might, however, behave differently.

---

### Q2: Is there a shorter way?

I think the most straightforward way to get the desired date format is to just copy the code from `australian.lbx` into `\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}` as show in [Format "visited on" date in "dd Month yyyy" format (example: "1 October 2006") in references list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/672529/35864). If you absolutely cannot live with that, you can try to make `british` an alias for `australian`, so that `biblatex` loads `australian.lbx` instead of `british.lbx` even when the main language is `british`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,date=year,urldate=long,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{australian}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{markey}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interestingly, Australian usage is a multi-format one, although the one defined in the .lbx is widespread and the most common. There is no (real) official standards body to define such things. Style guides (if any) can be used as a defacto standard for a discipline but these can vary and can even encourage departures from their "standard" in certain contexts. Consistency of usage is probably the only real requirement. (And being flexible. :) )